# Installing ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 13.04.

I tried to install the packages but I get the following message:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rospack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-fuerte-rospack : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-program-options1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-system1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do I understand from this that it is impossible to install fuerte on 13.04? I would agree if I would not be able to install it on a earlier ubuntu version but a higher version should not be a problem I presume?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76171/installing-ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-13.04/) by [WG-](https://answers.ros.org/users/2766/wg-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-09-03**:
I don't think 13.04 is officially supported, but one way to fix this would be to install the problematic packages manually. Although not in this specific circumstance, I've found that to help most of the time. That still might cause problems because of version conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte is not supported on Ubuntu Raring 13.04 http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte

You will need to use ROS Hydro

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on 2013-11-13**:
ROS groovy also works on Ubuntu 13.04